# Flutter getx refresh controller when back from another controller

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have a screen with a list of items , when I click on an item it opens a page with another controller with item details , item details contains a delete button , when I delete the item and go back to the first screen , the deleted item is still there and I must restart the app to disappear , How to make that approach ?

Comment: how you are deleting the item? could you please provide your code?

Comment: My list items is stored in the get storage .. the first screen I load the list from the storage .. the I navigate to the second page to the details of an item .. the I delete the item from the second page from storage but it is not updated in the list when I get back to the first screen

Comment: And I am using Getbuilder at both views with deferent controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the deleted item from your `ListController`'s list as well.
Your `DetailsController`'s `delete` method should look like this:

```
delete(int id) async{
  await itemService.delete(id);
  final ListController listController = Get.find();

  var index = listController.indexWhere((element) => element.id == id);

  listController.removeAt(index);
  listController.update();

 }
```

Comment: When to call it ?

Comment: On the `onPressed` of the delete button